# Dropbox file fetcher broken, API/Redirect update on their part?

Tags: php, dropbox

The script I used fetched a file from

https://www.dropbox.com/browse_plain/$REMOTEDIR?no_js=true

which now returns:

> HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
>
> Server: nginx/0.7.63
>
> Date: Mon, 24 May 2010 17:02:44 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> location: /home
>
> pragma: no-cache
>
> cache-control: no-cache
>
> Found
>
> ```
> <h1>Found</h1>
>
> <p>The resource was found at <a href="/home">/home</a>;
> ```
>
> you should be redirected
>   automatically.
>
> ```
> <hr noshade>
>
> <div align="right">WSGI Server</div>
> ```

Whereas the script has a method to parse a div from the source.

1. Can anyone confirm whether or not they have this issue with file fetching scripts? If not what method(s) are you using since there's no official API?

Comment: Dropbox now have an API, have you had a look at that? I have done a bit of work on it and it seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you are using is not respecting redirects. Generally browsers will see the `location: /home` header and make another request to that URL.

Comment: I understand that aspect of it, but how would I get the subdirectory part working since it's just a redirect to /home? I believe there was a reason the script used this url instead of `/home`, in addition to the no_js option.

Comment: `Location: /home` is not a valid HTTP header. The value of the `Location` header should be a full URL.